# Real part of a quotient

Tags: complex-numbers

Is there some fast way to know the real part of a quotient?

$$\Re\left(\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right)$$

$z_i\in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: try subtituting $z_i=a_i+i b_i = \Re{z_i}+i \ \Im{z_i}$ and write everything out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given $z_1=a+bi$ and $z_2=c+di$ then:$$\Re\left(\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right)=\frac{ac+bd}{c^2+d^2}$$

Comment: perfect...that should do it.

Comment: If we apply  you result to: $\frac{e^{i\pi}-1}{e^{i\pi/(M+1)}-1}=\frac{-2}{cos \alpha + i sin \alpha -1}$ where $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{M+1}$  so we obtain that real part of this quotient is $\frac{-2cos \alpha}{cos^2 \alpha-2 cos\alpha +1 + sin^2 \alpha}=\frac{cos\alpha}{cos\alpha -1}?$

Comment: @MathStudent: I think you obtain $\Re \left( \frac{e^{i \pi} - 1}{e^{i \alpha} - 1} \right) = \frac{-2(\cos \alpha - 1)}{(\cos \alpha - 1)^2 + \sin^2 \alpha} = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have $z_1$ and $z_2$ in a "nice" form eg some of the values of $e^{i\theta}$ for various $\theta$, you could use $1/2(z+\bar{z})=\Re{(z)}$.

So you'd get:

### $\Re(\frac{z_1}{z_2})=\frac{z_1\bar{z_2}+\bar{z_1}z_2}{2z_2\bar{z_2}}$

for
$z_1=r_1e^{i\theta_1}$

$z_2=r_2e^{i\theta_2}$

$\Re(\frac{z_1}{z_2})=\frac{r_1}{r_2}cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$

Just as an alternative, although I suspect you wanted something like user130512's post.

Answer (score 1):

*At user130512's request in a comment*, Euler's form. (I really suspect the calculation is going to get bad).

Let $z_1 = r_1e^{i\theta_1}$ and $z_2 = r_2e^{i\theta_2}$.

Now $\frac{z_1}{z_2} = \frac{r_1}{r_2}e^{i(\theta_1 - \theta_2)}$

Assuming $z_1 = a + ib, z_2 = c+id$

$$\Re\left(\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right) = \frac{r_1}{r_2}\cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac{b}{a}\right) - \arctan\left(\frac{d}{c}\right)\right)$$

**Disclaimer** This is for pure amusement. No practical point in doing this.